# How to increase value of a text variable in a file

Tags: shell, awk

file1.text contains below data.

```
VARIABLE=00
RATE=14
PRICE=100
```

I need to increment value by 1 only for below whenever I want.

VARIABLE=00  file name: file1.txt

output should be incremented by 1 every time.

output will be like below

VARIABLE=01

in next run VARIABLE=02 and so on....

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems. So kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I tried this but not working, changing for all and also it is not replacing 00 with 01

awk -F, '{$2=$2+1}1' OFS== file1.txt

VARIABLE=00=1
RATE=14=1
PRICE=100=1

Comment: Tried This also

awk -F"=" ' { OFS="=" } /VARIABLE/ { print $1,$2+1; } ' file1.txt

VARIABLE=1

here only one value is coming I need to print all value like 

VARIABLE=1
RATE=14
PRICE=100

Also need to change value of VARIABLE permanently every time.

Comment: Ok, please do add these commands in your post(question) always, I have added my answer now, kindly check it and comment in answer's comment section cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} /^VARIABLE/{$NF=sprintf("%02d",$NF+1)} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                            ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS="="                      ##Setting FS and OFS as = here.
}
/^VARIABLE/{                      ##Checking condition if line starts from VARIABLE then do following.
  $NF=sprintf("%02d",$NF+1)       ##Adding 1 last field and saing it to last field with 2 digits value.
}
1                                 ##1 will print the current line.
' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working fine but as value was changing in it is coming after adding 1.

I have tried with below command which is working as per my as per my expectation.

cat file1.txt | grep -v VARIABLE > file2.txt && awk -F"=" ' { OFS="=" } /VARIABLE/ { print $1,$2+1; } ' file1.txt >> file2.txt && mv file2.txt file1.txt

Comment: @SourinBiswas, sorry I didn't get it, could you please do let me know in more details whats not working?

Comment: after running your command VARIABLE value is being increased by 1 but as it is not changing value in file1.txt permanently It is coming again same value after 1 increment.

I need to get VARIABLE value updated by incensement 1 every time I run command , that is why I used below command.

cat file1.txt | grep -v VARIABLE > file2.txt && awk -F"=" ' { OFS="=" } /VARIABLE/ { print $1,$2+1; } ' file1.txt >> file2.txt && mv file2.txt file1.txt

Comment: @SourinBiswas, sure, please check my edited answer it saves output into Input_file itself, let me know how it goes then.

Comment: I added something after your command and it is working perfectly.


awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="} /^VARIABLE/{$NF=sprintf("%02d",$NF+1)} 1' file1.txt > file2.txt && mv file2.txt file1.txt

Answer (score 1):

You can do it quite simply as a one-liner in **Perl**:

```
perl -i -pe '/^VARIABLE=/ && s/(\d+)/$&+1/e' file
```

In case you are unfamiliar with **Perl**, that says...

> Run **Perl** and modify `file` in-place. if you come to any lines containing `VARIABLE=`, substitute the digits on that line with an expression calculated as *"whatever the number was +1"*

Note that **Perl** is a standard part of **macOS** - i.e. automatically included with all versions.