# bash multiply all the numbers in a file by a constant

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file with words and numbers. I want to multiply all the numbers in this file with a constant using some bash command.

My file looks like this:

```
192
TotEnergy=-1103.24236000 cutoff=-1.00000000 nneightol=1.20000000 pbc="T T T" Lattice="23.46511000       0.00000000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      23.46511000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      -0.00000100      23.46511000" Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:force:R:3:Z:I:1
O              11.72590000     14.59020000     25.33440000     -0.04213780      0.03788820      0.00314949       8
H              12.69400000     16.13880000     24.72010000     -0.03709700     -0.03453660      0.01566490       1
H               9.70021000     15.03790000     25.76530000      0.07676920     -0.00101183     -0.02270490       1
O              10.68010000      3.41217000      4.43292000     -0.01918440      0.01516070      0.03966070       8
H              10.14500000      3.90822000      6.40047000      0.01092440     -0.00643783     -0.08715890       1
H               9.97507000      4.53606000      3.00742000      0.01153240     -0.01693960      0.04267200       1
O              -1.28237000     20.66930000      0.33214000      0.01567000      0.05712230     -0.02019150       8
```

My main aim is to multiply the first three columns of lines that start with O or H. However, multiplying all the numbers also works and can be easily processed over.

**Expected output for constant=2**

```
192
TotEnergy=-1103.24236000 cutoff=-1.00000000 nneightol=1.20000000 pbc="T T T" Lattice="23.46511000       0.00000000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      23.46511000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      -0.00000100      23.46511000" Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:force:R:3:Z:I:1
O              23.45180000     29.18040000     50.66880000     -0.04213780      0.03788820      0.00314949       8
.
.
.
(similarly for other lines)
```

What bash command can be used to accomplish this?

Comment: Look at `awk` that is the most straight-forward tool for such tasks.

Comment: @EdMorton I am not looking for a qualitative answer. I have a defined expected output and an environment. The only broad part is the option to use any bash command to execute it. I sure hope that qualifies to be on-topic

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327472/2836621

Comment: Isn't this as simple as `awk '/^[OH]/{ $2*=100; $3*=100; $4*=100; }'`? `I have a defined expected output` You did not - what constant should the columns be multipled with?

Comment: Why is the first line, `192`, multiplied by 2 in your example? It does not start with O or H?

Comment: @fireball.1 : First of all, your numbers are floats an bash does not have floating point arithmetic, so you would have to revert to an external program such as `bc` (which in your case means **many** child processes, since you have many numbers), or use a shell which can do floats (_zsh_ for instance).

Comment: @user1934428 I think there is something missing in your story because using awk i was able to do float point multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mighty Perl for this:

```
$ perl -lape 'if (/^[OH]/) {for $i (1..3) {s/@F[$i]/sprintf("%.8f", @F[$i]*2)/e}}' file
```

Prints:

```
192
TotEnergy=-1103.24236000 cutoff=-1.00000000 nneightol=1.20000000 pbc="T T T" Lattice="23.46511000       0.00000000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      23.46511000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      -0.00000100      23.46511000" Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:force:R:3:Z:I:1
O              23.45180000     29.18040000     50.66880000     -0.04213780      0.03788820      0.00314949       8
H              25.38800000     32.27760000     49.44020000     -0.03709700     -0.03453660      0.01566490       1
H               19.40042000     30.07580000     51.53060000      0.07676920     -0.00101183     -0.02270490       1
O              21.36020000      6.82434000      8.86584000     -0.01918440      0.01516070      0.03966070       8
H              20.29000000      7.81644000      12.80094000      0.01092440     -0.00643783     -0.08715890       1
H               19.95014000      9.07212000      6.01484000      0.01153240     -0.01693960      0.04267200       1
O              -2.56474000     41.33860000      0.66428000      0.01567000      0.05712230     -0.02019150       8
```

Or `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^[OH]/ {for (i=2;i<=4;i++) $i=sprintf("%.8f", $i*2)} 1' file
```

If you want to maintain the column spacing, back to Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

open my $fh, '<', '/tmp/file' or die "Can't open file $!";

my $factor=2;
my @range=(1..3);

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^[OH]\h+/){
        my @field=split(/(?<=\H)(?=\h+|$)/);
        for my $i (@range) {
            my @comp=split(/\./, $field[$i]);
            my $decimals=length($comp[1]);
            my $field_width=length($field[$i]);
            my $new_num=sprintf("%.*f", $decimals, $field[$i]*$factor);
            $field[$i]=sprintf(" %*s", $field_width-1, $new_num);
        }
        say join('', @field);
    }
    else {
        say;
    }
}
```

Or with `gawk` (not POSIX awk):

```
$ gawk -v factor=2 'BEGIN{FPAT="([OH])|(\\s+[-]?[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)|(\\s+[0-9]+)"} 
    /^[OH]\s+/ {
        for(i=2;i<=3;i++){
            if (index($i, ".")) {
                split($i, a, "\\.")
                decimal = length(a[2])
            }   
            else
                decimal=0   
            $i=sprintf("%*s", length($i)-1, sprintf("%.*f", decimal, $i*factor)) 
        }
    }
    1' file
```

Both print:

```
192
TotEnergy=-1103.24236000 cutoff=-1.00000000 nneightol=1.20000000 pbc="T T T" Lattice="23.46511000       0.00000000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      23.46511000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      -0.00000100      23.46511000" Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:force:R:3:Z:I:1
O              23.45180000     29.18040000     50.66880000     -0.04213780      0.03788820      0.00314949       8
H              25.38800000     32.27760000     49.44020000     -0.03709700     -0.03453660      0.01566490       1
H              19.40042000     30.07580000     51.53060000      0.07676920     -0.00101183     -0.02270490       1
O              21.36020000      6.82434000      8.86584000     -0.01918440      0.01516070      0.03966070       8
H              20.29000000      7.81644000     12.80094000      0.01092440     -0.00643783     -0.08715890       1
H              19.95014000      9.07212000      6.01484000      0.01153240     -0.01693960      0.04267200       1
O              -2.56474000     41.33860000      0.66428000      0.01567000      0.05712230     -0.02019150       8
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution ( *with caution, because your question is missing expected output and some details on what you tried* ).

Open a text editor, and save the script below as `colmult`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S awk -f

BEGIN{
  # If constant m not provided, default to 10
  if (m==0) {
    m=10
  }
}

{
  # If first column is O or H
  if ($1 ~ /^[OH]$/) {
    for (c=2; c<=4; c++) {
      $c*=m # multiply column by constant m
      $c=sprintf("%.8f", $c) # format column's number
    }
  }
  print # printout the line
}
```

Make `colmult` executable.

Example with Linux shell:

```sh
chmod +x colmult
```

Then use this scripted command to multiply the first three columns of your `inputfile` by a constant number ( *here I choose the multiplier to be  `42.666` as an arbitrary example* ):

```sh
./colmult -v m=42.666 inputfile
```

Here is the output of processing your sample data with the awk script above:

```
192
TotEnergy=-1103.24236000 cutoff=-1.00000000 nneightol=1.20000000 pbc="T T T" Lattice="23.46511000       0.00000000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      23.46511000       0.00000000      -0.00000100      -0.00000100      23.46511000" Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:force:R:3:Z:I:1
O 500.29724940 622.50547320 1080.91751040 -0.04213780 0.03788820 0.00314949 8
H 541.60220400 688.57804080 1054.70778660 -0.03709700 -0.03453660 0.01566490 1
H 413.86915986 641.60704140 1099.30228980 0.07676920 -0.00101183 -0.02270490 1
O 455.67714660 145.58364522 189.13496472 -0.01918440 0.01516070 0.03966070 8
H 432.84657000 166.74811452 273.08245302 0.01092440 -0.00643783 -0.08715890 1
H 425.59633662 193.53553596 128.31458172 0.01153240 -0.01693960 0.04267200 1
O -54.71359842 881.87635380 14.17108524 0.01567000 0.05712230 -0.02019150 8
```