# How to increment the numbers in a file by 3 in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script that adds 3 to the number in the file.

**original file (test.tcl)**

```
node_(0) setdest ~~
node_(1) setdest ~~
node_(2) setdest ~~
node_(3) setdest ~~
```

**changed file**

```
node_(3) setdest ~~
node_(4) setdest ~~
node_(5) setdest ~~
node_(6) setdest ~~
```

But I have no idea how to write the script.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327472/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you so much for your reply. I tried revising the code in the link you attached. By the way, nothing has changed in my files. Can you please check that I am making a mistake in the code? Thank you

Below is the code I modified.. (0321.tcl is original file)
`perl -i -pe'/^node_/ && s/(\d+)/$&+3/e' 0321.tcl`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Oh I think I found the reason. The sentences in my program did not start with'node_'. I don't think it has changed because there are other characters in front! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sorry I didn't know much about Linux so I thought it was a Linux shell. I corrected the question and tag.

Comment: I don't know how to write a script, but this might be useful: using the dollar-sign and two subsequent brackets, you can do some basic calculation, e.g. `echo $((4+3))` reveals `7`.

Comment: This should work `perl -i -pe 's/(\d+)/$&+3/e' file`