# Is there a sed or perl expression to increment a specific number in a file?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file with two lines, The numbers in the file when written to will vary ranging from 01 to over 100. For example:

```
ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web59 /dev/itest17/dbs_web59
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n rdsk_web59 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4
```

I need to increment the ending number (in this case it is 59) by one.

Resulting in:

```
ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web60 /dev/itest17/dbs_web60
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n rdsk_web60 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4
```

Notice how `/dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4` does not get incremented,

So is it possible to take in account the scenario of:

```
ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web04 /dev/itest17/dbs_web04
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n rdsk_web04 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4
```

Resulting in

```
ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web05 /dev/itest17/dbs_web05
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n rdsk_web05 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4
```

The lines in the file can vary (the path that is) such as:

```
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n dbs_saleitem_f105 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_std3
ln -s/dev/vg_ifmx_test_std3/rdbs_saleitem_f105/dev/itest7/saleitem_f105
```

Would result in:

```
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n dbs_saleitem_f106 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_std3
ln -s/dev/vg_ifmx_test_std3/rdbs_saleitem_f106/dev/itest7/saleitem_f106
```

So using something as `perl -i -pe '/ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web/` would not be possible since the path is not always the same in the file.

Is there a way to use sed or awk/perl to create an expression to do this? I am new to shell scripting and using these commands. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Easy with Perl... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327472/2836621

Comment: If your paths could include spaces, e.g. if `/dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web04` could be `/dev/foo bar/rdsk_web04`, then you should include that case in your sample input/output.

Comment: So you just want to identify the final number in the first line and then replace all occurrences in the file with that value incremented by one?  It would be helpful if you would show the expected output for the sample you show with `dbs_saleitem_f105 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_std3`.  I presume in that case you want to replace all instance of `105` with `106`, but it's not clear to me if you want the 2nd 105 in the second line to be replaced.  If you can provide an accurate and specific description of what you want to do, then you will be 98% done.

Comment: @William Pursell yes, that is correct. I updated the question, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 'if ($. == 1) {
              ($n) = ($m) = /([0-9]+)$/;
              ++$m;
              s/$n/$m/g;
          } else {
              s/$n(?= )/$m/;
          }' file
```

Comment: is there a way to have this write to the file itself? I believe running this just prints out the result, not writing to the file. It seems to work in that sense though so thank you.

Comment: Use `-i~` to change the file itself, creating a backup with the `~` suffix.

Comment: I tried running perl -i 'code' file, and it is giving an error saying it is trying to open that entire code block. No such file or directory. @choroba

Comment: @ctheising98: It's always `-e 'code'`, and `-p` to autoprint the processed lines.

Comment: To put it another way, run it like so: `perl -i~ -pe 'if ($. == 1) { ... } ' file`

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for the third arg to `match()`:

```
awk '
    match($0,/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)( .*[^0-9])([0-9]+)/,a) {
        a[2]++
        a[4] += (NR==1 ? 1 : 0)
        $0 = a[1] a[2] a[3] a[4]
    }
    { print }
' file
ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web60 /dev/itest17/dbs_web60
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n rdsk_web60 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4
```

To write the output back to the original file just change `awk` to `awk -i inplace`.

Comment: When running this i got
 `syntax error The source line is 2.

 The error context is

                    match($0,/(.*[^0-9])([0-9]+)( >>>  .*[^0-9])([0-9]+)/, <<<
 awk: Quitting

 The source line is 2.`

Comment: Then you aren't running GNU awk as I said is required. Get GNU awk - it has more useful features than any other awk variant and has excellent support and documentation.

Comment: I am not allowed to add anything to this server. The solution using perl works for printing the result. But I am having trouble writing it to the file. @ Ed Morton. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web04 /dev/itest17/dbs_web04
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n rdsk_web04 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4

awk '{
      gsub(/web[0-9][0-9]/,
           "web"sprintf("%0.2d",gensub(/.*web([0-9][0-9]).*/, "\\1",1)+1))
}1' file

ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web05 /dev/itest17/dbs_web05
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n rdsk_web05 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to either set a variable that can be trivially changed, or use a templating language to create the file. Either seems simpler to maintain and less brittle than awk/perl/etc.

If "file" will be executed by a shell:

```
N=60
ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web$N /dev/itest17/dbs_web$N
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n rdsk_web$N /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4
```

Now it is trivial to change the first line.

Or, if you want to keep the original format:

```
# generate the file from template
mkfile(){
    cat <<EOD
ln -s /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4/rdsk_web$1 /dev/itest17/dbs_web$1
/usr/sbin/lvcreate -L 2048 -n rdsk_web$1 /dev/vg_ifmx_test_core4
EOD
}

# ...
mkfile 60 >/path/to/file
# ...

for n in 59 60 04 05; do
    # ...
    mkfile $n >/path/to/file
    # ...
fi
```