# Is there perl line to increment a number in a line in a file?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file with one line like:

```
onspaces -a dataidx -p /dev/itest17/idx_dataidx20 -o 0 -s 2097150
```

I need to increment the number by one so the output would be:

```
onspaces -a dataidx -p /dev/itest17/idx_dataidx21 -o 0 -s 2097150
```

The could also have a line such as:

```
onspaces -a dataidx -p /dev/itest17/foobar01 -o 0 -s 2097150
```

which would result in

```
onspaces -a dataidx -p /dev/itest17/foobar02 -o 0 -s 2097150
```

I have tried

```
`perl -i -pe 'if ($. == 1) 
{($n) = ($m) = /([09]+)$/;
++$m;s/$n/$m/g;
} else {s/$n(?= )/$m/;}' in_file`
```

which was a solution to a previous question that I asked that was solved, but this one seems to be a bit different. Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm using an ancient version of Perl, 5.8.3.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to increment? The first number before a space? Leading zeroes included?

Comment: Like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63327472/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell: That doesn't work with leading zeroes.

Comment: I want to increment the number at the end of the path. In the examples above the 20 and the 02.

Comment: Yes, but how do you recognise the end of a path? By a space, right?

Comment: yes the path should always have " -o 0 -s...." after it

Comment: When you say "[your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72804265/10971581)" you should credit the person who took the time to write it for you. Otherwise it looks like you are claiming that you wrote that code yourself, which would be plagiarism.

Comment: @jhnc thanks for catching my poorly worded question

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to the solution I provided to you previously:

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/([0-9]+)(?= -o)/$x = $1; ++$x/e' file
```

I.e. find a sequence of digits `[0-9]+` followed by a space and -o `(?= -o)`, replace the digits by the incremented number. The `/e` interprets the replacement as a code to run, using `++` ensures the leading zeroes are kept.

Comment: @zdim: Added `-o` the space.

Answer (score 2):

The only really "moving part" here is about finding the place in the line where that number is.  It appears that it is the end of a path following `-p`

```
perl -pe's{\-p\s+/\S+[^0-9]\K([0-9]+)\b}{ $n = $1; ++$n }e' file
```

Prints as expected on the provided input.  The "maneuver" with `$n` (instead of just `1+$1`) is there to ensure that the leading zero(s) stay.<sup>†</sup> To change the file in-place add `-i`, as in the question, after thorough testing.

This makes assumptions, since the quetion isn't very precise (for example, that paths have no spaces). It can be tweaked, and perhaps simplified, depending on requirements' details.

---

A brief explanation and alternatives

The `/e` modifier makes the replacement side be evaluated as code so we can do our math there, and what that code returns is then used as the replacement. The `\K` nicely "drops" everything matched up to that point, so the replcement won't touch previous matches.

However, comments clarify that this is perl v5.8.3; `\K` wasn't there back then (twenty years ago). Without it we have to capture everything preceding the number to change, and put it back

```
perl -pe's{(\-p\s+/\S+[^0-9])([0-9]+)\b}{ $n=$2; $1.(++$n) }e' file
```

Finally, the `[^0-9]` (not a digit) is there to "stop" the previous greediness of `\S+`, needed to match a path, so that the last number in the path can be matched in full (`\S+` would only leave one digit for the final `[0-9]+`).

---

<sup>†</sup> When a number is used in numeric context it can be expected to lose the leading zero(s) (ie, it normally does). However, with the [auto-increment operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement) it doesn't if it is used as a string, and in the replacement side of a regex it is.

A trick from `jhnc` in a comment keeps it compact, too

```
perl -pe's{(\-p\s+/\S+[^0-9])\K([0-9]+)\b}{ ++($_=$1) }e' file
```

or, in the perl-5.8.3-has-no-`\K` case

```
perl -pe's{(\-p\s+/\S+[^0-9])([0-9]+)\b}{ $1.(++($_=$2)) }e' file
```

Comment: Do you know why this is having the prompt display ">" after running that line  as if the prompt is asking for further input rather than just printing the result?

Comment: @ctheising98 The closing `'` was missing in the original posting (typo), just updated ... try again?

Comment: I tried and it just printed the same line

Comment: `informix~itest17: cat onspace.txt`
`onspaces -a dataidx -p /dev/itest17/idx_dataidx20 -o 0 -s 2097150
`
`informix~itest17: perl -pe's{\-p\s+/\S+\K([0-9]+)\b}{ 1+$1 }e' onspace.txt
`
`onspaces -a dataidx -p /dev/itest17/idx_dataidx20 -o 0 -s 2097150
`

Comment: i copied and pasted your echo "" line in the comments and mine still returned 20

Comment: What system are youo on and with what perl (`perl -v`)?

Comment: @zdim: It won't work for numbers with a leading zero

Comment: Perl v5.8.3 on Unix

Comment: @ctheising98 oh?  perl 5.8 -- that's 20 (twenty) years old (see [version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_5_version_history))

Comment: 5.8.3? Time to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I know it's old but I don't think I can change it as I'm writing this for a team that deals with multiple servers running this version, so updating is probably not an option. Another server that will be using this script is running 5.8.8

Comment: @zdmin that line seems to work

Comment: `1+$1` -> `++($_=$1)` or somesuch handles leading zeros using perl's magic string increment

Comment: @ctheising98 Updated with a fix for the regex pattern

Comment: @ctheising98 Updated with a fix to make sure to always keep the leading zero(s)